# Delayed double click for editing textblock WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am trying to make it so a certain textblock turns editable with a delayed double click. Similar to the functionality in Windows Explorer when you do a delayed double click to edit file and folder names. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing in Windows Explorer is a single-click on a selected/focused item initiating a rename operation.  The first click you're seeing actually selects/focuses the item and the second click initiates the rename operation.  You can verify this by using the keyboard to select a different item and then single-clicking on the newly selected item.

It appears that there is a short duration (e.g. half a second) between the click on a selected/focused item and the UI going into rename mode.  So... if an item is clicked on which already has focus, you'll need to do something like starting a timer.  If that item still has focus when the timer expires, enter your renaming mode.

From there it is just a matter of applying the correct template with whichever trigger/flag logic you care to implement.

**EDIT**:  Do a search on WPF [in-place editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923851/how-do-i-fully-implement-in-place-editing-in-a-listbox) and you should find some code examples.

**NOTE**:  The F2 key also tends to initiate rename operations on selected items if you want to wire that in as well.

Comment: So should I do all this in the clickevent of the textblock?

Comment: It depends ;)  You should be consistent in where you handle things like this in your app - either in code behind, a view model, custom control, etc.  Also, you'll probably need to use something like MouseDown instead of Click.

Comment: Yeah, meant mouse click event. Though mousedown doesn't seem to be doing anything. The solution you linked seems overly complex. Seems like the timer method you said above would work just fine without having to create custom classes and what not.